# How do I style my lists in Word so that the first item in a nested list is inline?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, list

I have a list that appears as so:

```
LIST ITEM TITLE
                   1)
                        (a) List Item
                        (b) List Item
                        (c) List Item
LIST ITEM TITLE
                   2)
                        (a) List Item
                        (b) List Item
                        (c) List Item
```

And I want to style it to look like this:

```
LIST ITEM TITLE    1)   (a) List Item
                        (b) List Item
                        (c) List Item

LIST ITEM TITLE    2)   (a) List Item
                        (b) List Item
                        (c) List Item
```

Is there a way I can style my lists to look this way without putting them in tables and manually inputing the parent list numbers?

Comment: Yeah I think you need to use a sequence field - never done it though